# PCoA/MDS on sqrt transformed Bray-Curtis dissmilarity using cmdscale

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, ecology, euclidean, diversity

I would like to use PCoA to visualize beta diversity of a large community. I chose Bray-Curtis as distance measure to calculate the dissimilarity matrix and would like to apply a square root transformation as suggested here
https://www.davidzeleny.net/anadat-r/doku.php/en:pcoa_nmds
and by Legendre ea 2012,2018.

so far my code is as follows

```
my_dist <- vegdist(mydata, method="bray")
is.euclid(sqrt(my_dist)) #check pcoa assumptions
pcoa <- **cmdscale(sqrt(my_dist))**
```

my question is basically if base R can handle this input[ mainly cmdscale(sqrt(my_dist))]
correctly and if my code is useful to calculate the pcoa as described above.
Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am a bit puzzled by the statement that taking the square root makes it metric. The problem with Bray-Curtis dissimilarity is that it does not obey triangle inequality. A monotonic transform is not going to change this

Comment: Refering to Zelený? Perhaps it should say Euclidean, but I'm not very well versed in mathematics. I mainly tried to make sense of  Num Ecology with R and made some adaptions

Comment: why not visualise using non-metric multidimensional scaling (nmds) instead? This can handle Bray-Curtis without needing to transform

Comment: @rw2 that was my initial approach, but nmds failed to converge even after I made some adaptions as suggested in ?metaMDS()